# How to hide the righthand border of a column in an MS Word table using delphi XE5

Tags: delphi, ms-word

I am creating a word document with a table in it using Delphi. The table has 2 columns.
The code below is creating the table, making the top row double border and hiding the left column.

```
wrdDoc.Tables.Add(wrdSelection.Range,12,2);
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Rows.Alignment := wdAlignRowLeft;

 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).SetWidth(155,wdAdjustNone);
 wrdDoc.Tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(2).SetWidth(299,wdAdjustNone);
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle := wdLineStyleSingle;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderRight).LineStyle := wdLineStyleSingle;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle := wdLineStyleSingle;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderTop).LineStyle := wdLineStyleSingle;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle := wdLineStyleSingle;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle := wdLineStyleSingle;

  //Top Row double Border
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Rows.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle := wdLineStyleDouble;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Rows.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderRight).LineStyle := wdLineStyleDouble;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Rows.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle := wdLineStyleDouble;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Rows.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderTop).LineStyle := wdLineStyleDouble;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Rows.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle := wdLineStyleDouble;

 //Left Column no Border
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderTop).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
 wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
```

The only problem is. For some reason the below code does not work.

```
wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
```

It keeps telling me `"The requested member of the collection does not exist"` and i cannot find the reason. In the above lines it works. But not when i try to remove the middle lines in the left column.

Any help would be great. Thank You.

Comment: a) Should your title read "... Right Column Border ..."?  b) Are you sure that wdBorderVertical is what you want?  Change it temporarily to wdBorderRight, then put a breakpoint on the  wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone; line.  Then single step through those four lines.  Is that the effect you want?  If so, I'll write it up as an answer;  if not, you need to describe how what you want should differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:  temporarily comment-out the four lines of code below your "//Left Column no Border" comment and insert this in their place:

```
  wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle := wdLineStyleNone;
```

Word doesn't complain about the requested element not existing, so it seems that Word's objection is specific to

```
  wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderVertical)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way of finding out from Word which of the wdBorderxxxx values are acceptable in a given context short of trying them and seeing whether it objects.

If changing wdBorderVertical to wdBorderRight in the line that gives you the error doesn't give the visual effect you're after, please add a screenshot of what you *do* want.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.

```
wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderVertical)
```

cannot be exceucted because i am addressing a column. A column has no verticle lines in it. I should have addressed it like so.

```
wrdDoc.tables.Item(1).Columns.Item(1).Borders.Item(wdBorderHorizontal)
```

Thank you guys anyway very much.